# Where's my memory! all ram gone under Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016

I'm checking a server that has 32gb of ram and I see 99% memory usage.

The machine is used with IIS, MongoDB and ElasticSearch.

None of the processes seemed to be that big. The largest was MongoDB at about 1gb.

So, I shut down everything.. and now that memory usage is 88%

After a reboot, with all services running, the memory usage is 23%

[image: 88% memory usage without large processes]

[image: Largest processes]

Those are the largest processes on the system, with everything being shutdown. As you can see, everything is very small, but most of the ram remains gone.

How can I track what is eating up all the ram? I tried process explorer, but it doesn't give me any more useful info.

Comment: Explaining in a comment why one votes to close down the question would be useful. I'm presenting a situation that can't be tracked with the usual tools and ask what other options there are. I fail to see how this could be a bad question.

Comment: Why do you have a compiler on your server?

Comment: It does it's own build with team city

Comment: A decent OS never leaves memory unused.  It is only going to be a low number right after a reboot when there has not been any real disk activity.  Google "windows file system cache" to learn more.

Comment: the file cache, like in Linux, doesn't count toward memory used.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use RAMMAP from sysinternals it will give you more details about memory usage. Like metaFile for example.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch generally a lot of the available RAM to cache search results aggregation. This is to avoid memory swapping. It's very evident and observable in LINUX servers. Thus it's recommended using ES in separate server in production with heavy usage.

So please try and check cache memory once.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Heap size allotted to Elasticsearch. You could check the values of `-Xms` and `-Xmx` in `jvm.options` file. Usually, 50% of physical RAM is allotted to ES and with `bootstrap.memory_lock` set to true, it locks the RAM. Ideally, as another answer mentions, Elasticsearch should be run in its own machine.